# How do you enter an OOTO time on the Outlook Calendar that covers a period of two weeks?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I am a new Outlook user and I would like to enter my vacation time on the calendar, repeated OOTO for two weeks.  I was told that the manner in which I have done it is wrong.  What is the correct way to input repeated events on the calendar?

Comment: What is an OOTO time, and why is that relevant to the question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Is OOTO `out of the office`? If so, I think it's more commonly described as OOO (out of office) or even OOF (out of oFfice)!

Answer (score 1):

File -> Automatic Replies

Then click the checkbox for 'Only Send during this time range' and select your range.